# jQuery : change span value on option select

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Working on a project for a client... I want to change the value of the span of #sandy based on the selection choice of the dropdown. So for instance if Option Text 1 is selected, span #sandy will say: "This is for #sandy2", if Option Text 2 is selected, span #sandy will say "This is NOT for #sandy2".

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN""http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">

<head>
<meta content="text/html; charset=utf-8" http-equiv="Content-Type" />
<title>SANDBOX TEST</title>
<script>
function checkField(val)
{
alert("The input value has changed. The new value is: " + val);
}
</script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
i = 0;
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#clientname").keyup(function () {
        $("#pizza").text(i += 1);
        var stt = $(this).val();
        $("#sandy2").text(stt);
    });
});
</script>
</head>
<body>
<p>Modify the text in the input field, then click outside the field to fire onchange.    </p>
<table style="width: 300px">
<tr>
    <td style="width: 150px">Enter some text: </td>
    <td> 
    <input type="text" name="txt" id="clientname" value="" onchange="checkField(this.value)" style="width: 150px"/></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td style="width: 150px">Selection:</td>
    <td> <select name="Select1" style="width: 150px" onchange="jsFunction()">
            <option value="" disabled selected style="display:none;">Choose An Option!</option>
            <option>Option Text 1</option>
            <option>Option Text 2</option>
        </select></td>
</tr>
</table>
<br/>
======================================
<br/>
<span id="sandy">This is a test for <span id="sandy2"></span></span>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Give the `select` an id, and give each option a value:

```
<select id="selector" name="Select1" style="width: 150px" onchange="jsFunction()">
        <option value="" disabled selected style="display:none;">Choose An Option!</option>
        <option value="1">Option Text 1</option>
        <option value="2">Option Text 2</option>
</select>
```

Then when the `select` is changed, you can get the selected value like this:

```
var selected = $('#selector option:selected').val();
```

Then in your change handler, or your keyup handler, you can get the selected value and do things accordingly.

---

Additionally, it is bad practice to mix inline handlers with jQuery.

Remove onchange from the line

```
<select id="selector" name="Select1" style="width: 150px" onchange="jsFunction()">
```

and add it like this:

```
$(function() {
  $('#selector').on('change', jsFunction);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

i do not get your point. But  what ever i understand according that .
or you can seen http://jsfiddle.net/X83ex/1/

```
<select name="Select1" id="selection" style="width: 150px" onchange="jsFunction(this)">
        <option value="" disabled selected style="display:none;">
          Choose An Option!       
       </option>
        <option>Option Text 1</option>
        <option>Option Text 2</option>
    </select>
```

you can write in your javascript as .

```
function jsFunction(that){
    $('#sandy2').text($(that).val());
}
```

Comment: It is such bad practice to mix inline handlers with jQuery

Comment: i agree with you Joe.